# ExtJS 4.2.0 loading nested JSON data in grid

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, grid

I have a script which returns the following JSON

```
{
   "success":true,
   "code":0,
   "message":"works",
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"connection1",
         "status":1,
         "info":[
            {
               "info1":"abc",
               "info2":"def",
               "info3":"123"
            },
            {
               "info1":"ghi",
               "info2":"jkl",
               "info3":"456"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"connection2",
         "status":1,
         "info":[
            {
               "info1":"mno",
               "info2":"pqr",
               "info3":"789"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"connection3",
         "status":1,
         "info":[
            {
               "info1":"stu",
               "info2":"vwx",
               "info3":"123"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"connection4",
         "status":0,
         "info":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"connection5",
         "status":0,
         "info":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want `name`, `status` and the `info's` to be loaded into a grid.
So I first defined my data-model:

```
Ext.define("Data", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['name', 'status']
        });
```

then my info-model:

```
Ext.define("Info", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                'info1',
                'info2',
                'info3'
            ],
            belongsTo: 'Data'
        });
```

and set up my store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: "Data",
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'valid/URL.php'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }

        });
```

but my `console.debug(store)` logs `data: items: Array[0]`.
I tried to add

```
hasMany: { model: 'Info', name: 'info' }
```

to my data-model, but then my `console.debug(store)` logs `model: undefined`.

Does anyone know where my mistake is? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/44j) demonstrating the working code

The method to execute to get a corresponding hasMany store is `info()`:
`store.data.items[0].info()`

Also, in your example the reader is placed improperly. It should be within the proxy definition.  I'm not sure if this was just an error when copy/pasting code. Here is the corresponding models and store:

**Info Model:**

```
Ext.define("Info", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['info1', 'info2', 'info3'],
            belongsTo:'Data'
        });
```

**Data Model:**

```
Ext.define("Data", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['name', 'status'],
            hasMany:{model:'Info',name:'info'}
        });
```

**Store:**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: "Data",
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        });
```

And the log for demonstration after load:

```
store.on('load', function() {
            console.log(store.data.items[0].info());
        })
```

Comment: Hi Weeksdev, Thanks for your answer.
Could you please see the following json structure and help me to load data for same?

{
   "success":true,
   "code":0,
   "message":"works",
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"connection1",
         "status":1,
         "info1":[
            "one", "two", "three", "four"
         ],
         "info2":[
            "ten", "two", "eight", "four"
         ]
      }]

}